# Can't override Excel shortcuts via VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, vba

So I've got a bunch of keyboard shortcuts mapped to various macros for my worksheets. Normally they work fine, but suddenly a bunch of them aren't working.

What's weird is this is inconsistent. So a shortcut ctrl+q will work fine, but ctrl+alt+r won't (ctrl+alt+r instead changes the format of the cells I have highlighted).

This is true across all spreadsheets I'm using - it looks like any shortcut involving the Alt key isn't getting mapped.

What's really weird is that running these exact same spreadsheets on a different computer works fine.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does "Alt + Tab" or "Ctrl + Alt + Del" work?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that like some set of shortcuts aren't getting re-mapped - so things like ctrl+alt+r will perform their default excel behaviour, not the macro I've mapped them to with Application.OnKey

Comment: Does your keyboard have more than `ALT` key ??

Comment: Could the problem be with "File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings"?

Comment: Don't think so - Enable all macros is selected. And, as I said, some Application.OnKey mappings are working - some are not (and if I run for example Application.OnKey "%^r", "my_macro" in an immediate window, the key-binding does not get mapped)

Comment: May be this happens that recently the Hot key combination  ctrl+alt+r has been assigned to a Macro. Since this combination is working but  performing other job.

Comment: Currently ctrl+alt+r changes the formatting of the cells highlighted (I assume this is the default excel shortcut) - I cannot assign it to a Macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem - in case anyone else is struggling with a similar problem, it turned out to be a known issue with upgrading to Bloomberg Anywhere. To disable, go to Bloomberg->Options->Hot Key Manager, and untick Enable Bloomberg Hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

*Sometimes no particular cause behind the issue because it can happen due to corrupted Keyboard Drivers, Registry and Windows files, sometimes 3rd party Apps might be interfering with the keyboard.*

*So, I would like to suggest few possible methods to fix the issue.*

**Method 1:**

1.Press Windows Key + X and then select Control Panel.

2.Click Ease of Access inside Control Panel and then click “Change how your keyboard works.“

3.Make sure to uncheck Turn on Sticky Keys, Turn on Toggle Keys and Turn on Filter Keys.

4.Click Apply followed by OK.

5.Reboot the Computer to save changes.

**Method 2:**

1.Press Windows Key + X then select Command Prompt Admin.

2.Try these command sin sequence:

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

3.If the above command doesn’t work then try on the below:

Dism /Image:C:\offline /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:c:\test\mount\windows 
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:c:\test\mount\windows /LimitAccess

**NB:** Replace the C:\RepairSource\Windows with the location of your repair source (Windows Installation or Recovery Disc).

4.Reboot your Computer to save changes.

**Method 3:**

1.Press WindowsKey + R then type Regedit and hit Enter to open Registry Editor.

2.Navigate to the following registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout.

3.Now in the right-window make sure there is Scancode Map key.

4.If the above key is present then right-click on it and select Delete.

5.Now again navigate to the following registry location:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

6.In the right window pane look for NoWinKeys key and double click on it to change its value.

7.Enter 0 in value data field in order to disable NoWinKeys function.

**Note, if nothing works then better either Re-Install keyboard drivers or use the ultimate choice System Restore.**

*I do hope any of these will work for you.*